# foreach through dataset to compare textbox text C#

Tags: c#, sql

Im getting really stuck trying to iterate through a dataset to check if the company name entered into a textbox (TXTBXCustomerLookup) matches any of the entries in the dataset in column "CompanyName" when the button is pressed

So far I have this:

```
private void BTNLookupCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text != "") && (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text != " "))
        {
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        if (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text = this.CompanyName.ToString())
                        {
                            BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = true;
                            BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it is coming up with the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'String' to 'Bool" and "Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method"

These errors are on the line below

```
if (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text = this.CompanyName.ToString())
```

I  know it must be something simple I'm doing wrong but cannot think what and have spend over an hour trying to figure it out (using old trusty google)

Comment: `=` must be `==`. But it is smarter to put the `CompanyName.ToString()` outside of the loop, like as the first line of your code: `string toCompareTo = this.CompanyName.ToString();` and then inside the loop do an `if (blah.Text == toCompareTo) ...`

Comment: your comparing this.CompanyName wth the textbox text. Sure its not supposed to compare the textbox value with item from the last foreach? If your comparison is correct you dont really need any of the foreach statements wich seems kind of odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text == this.CompanyName.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two = signs. Otherwise your trying to assign the compannyname value to your TXTBXCustormerLookup textbox.

```
if (TXTBXCustomerLookup.Text == this.CompanyName.ToString()){
    BTNUpdateCustomer.Enabled = true;
    BTNDeleteCustomer.Enabled = true;
}
```